# React component Class in the configuration object is undefined in the target js file

Tags: reactjs

I need to render a component based on the configuration.
However I'm getting an error.
The problem can be seen in [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5kv8np0y5p)
However if i put the Box class in the same file it works! [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xp9znv8yn4)
Do you have any idea it isn't working.

Comment: in you first code sandbox example you are importing config from config file. But as I see config.js and box.js is empty that's why "TypeError
Cannot read property 'config' of undefined" is shown.

Comment: Please check it again. I shared it before saving

Answer (score 2):

Worked, Please look at the changes.

define `Box` component in its own file.
import `Box` in `config.js` and `export const config = { config: Box }`
now import `config` in index.js.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0o645k5y3v

Comment: it's working for me https://pasteboard.co/GP9F6le.png. Try the above link and check it once again

Comment: Thanks @Narasimha, i don't know why it was not working before. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can´t write comments, so goes in answer box:

Where is you config component? Can you place here in question? I could not see it in codesandbox.
From the code I saw, you call:

Is your intention render the component, if you have a render() function you should call , or please put the config component code here (or in the codesandbox if not yet).

Comment: Please check it again, i shared before saving